# search through nested objects based on values

Tags: elasticsearch

The data I have looks like

```
{
{'outer1':'value1','outer2':'value2','nested': 
    {'inner1':'innerval1','inner2':'innerval2',..}}, 
...
}
```

I am new to elasticsearch. I am trying to right a query to get all the matches for nested.innerval = 'xyz'.

I tried the following query -

```
`es.search(index='index1',body={'query':{'regexp':{'nested':{'.*':'xyz'}}}})`
```

But this failed. Hope you guys can help. Thank you

Comment: xyz is value that can be associated with any key of dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
Needed to use '[query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)'